# angular typeof guard error while compiling

Tags: javascript, angular

im starting a new `angular` project, but getting the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(11,5): error TS2740: Type
>   'typeof LoginGuard' is missing the following properties from type
>   'any[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.

what does `typeof` loginGuard acually mean, and what do I need to do to make it work as it's intended to?

Here is my route file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { LoginlandingComponent} from "./loginlanding/loginlanding.component";
import { LoginGuard} from "./login.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: LoginGuard,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: LoginlandingComponent
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my guard file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CanActivate, Router, Route } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements  CanActivate  {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (false) {
      console.log("its true");
      return true;
    }
  console.log("redirecting");
    // navigate to login page
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`canActivateChid` should be an [array value](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#canActivateChild).
Change the route definition to:

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [LoginGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: LoginlandingComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Note also that you are implementing the wrong interface. If you want to use that guard for child routes, you need to implement [`CanActivateChild`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)

Comment: Good solution , I was also missing the square brackets which was causing the error